# Connecting nodejs to google cloud SQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to connect an instance of nodejs to my google cloud SQL database. its failing.

I run the command

```
node server.js
```

and get the error

```
Problem with MySQL Error: connect ENETUNREACH
```

here is my server.js file

```
var gcloud = require("gcloud");
var express = require("express");
var mysql = require("mysql");
var app = express();
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
host : "2001:****:****:*:****:****:****:****",
user : "root",
password : "*****",
database : "scripto_5_k"
});
/* Connection to Database */
connection.connect(function(error){
if(error)
{
console.log("Problem with MySQL "+error);
}
else
{
console.log("Connected with Database ");
}
});
/*start the server */
app.listen(3000,function(){
console.log("its started on PORT 3000");
});
```

I have gone to my sql database in the developers console and allowed the ip address of my home and the node js instance but I cant seem to find the problem.

Any help is really appreciated.

**Update 1**

I pinged the IPv6 address with this result

```
C:\Users\joe>ping 2001:****:****:*:****:****:****:****

Pinging 2001:****:****:*:****:****:****:**** with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 2001:****:****:*:****:****:****:****:
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```

But I have taken the ip from the properties in the sql tab on gcloud.

Answer (score 1):

Host address might be wrong. have you tried to ping it?

Comment: I tried to ping it there but got no response. but its the ip is the one on the gcloud sql database. am I doing something wrong? its a IPv6 address